# Getting Skein to Work with Python

Tags: python, skein

I've been trying for quite a while now.  After I finally got Skein for python to install from [here](http://pythonhosted.org/pyskein/download.html).  I keep getting the following error:

> from _skein import skein256, skein512, skein1024, threefish
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Trying again using the 32bit version of Python resulted in this error:

> DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I'm not really sure what to do at this point.  Any ideas?

Comment: Someones been on **[XKCD](http://almamater.xkcd.com/)** lately :P

Comment: Hahahaha, not necessarily...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the 64bit version of python installed? Try the 32bit.

Comment: Trying the 32bit changed the error to:  `DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`